# custom imports/non-local classes in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I was attempting to use [this](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/packages.html) and [this](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?316549-AS3-How-to-import-and-use-my-custom-class) to figure out how to set up some math classes (the sin/cos functions I use for anything top down.) but I have it set to import package.class (the names of course.) but It said that "defintion package:Class not found". This confuses me and I am going to assume I have to do something with folders. However I'm not sure what folders to put it in/what to do to enter things specifically in a folder.

```
//import sthreets.CustomFuncs;

private function Movement()
        {
            if(LEFT==true)
            {
                rotation=rotation-6;
            }
            if(RIGHT==true)
            {
                rotation=rotation+6;
            }
            if(UP==true)
            {
                //x=x+CustomFuncs.TopDownMove("x", rotation, 0);
                //y=y+CustomFuncs.TopDownMove("y", rotation, 0);
            }
            if(DOWN==true)
            {
                //x=x-CustomFuncs.TopDownMove("x", rotation, 0);
                //y=y-CustomFuncs.TopDownMove("y", rotation, 0);
            }
        }
```

Commented out stuff was giving me errors, here's the CustomFuncs code.

```
package sthreets 
{

    public class CustomFuncs 
    {

        public function CustomFuncs() 
        {

        }

        public function TopDownMove(xy:String, rot:Number, offSet:Number):Number
        {
            if(xy=="x")
            {
                return cos(DegreesToRadions(rot)+offSet)
            }
            if(xy=="y")
            {
                return sin(DegreesToRadions(rot)+offSet)
            }
        }

        public function DegreesToRadions(rot:Number):Number
        {
            return rot*Math.PI/180;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Whould you be kind and show us your code?

Comment: Edited it in, the commented out bit in the first one is what was giving me the error, the second one is the CustomFuncs as file, inside of a folder called "sthreets".

Answer (score 1):

Package names are determined by the location from src. `src/my/package/name` is `my.package.name`. The package you import at the top of any class **must** match the actual package, otherwise the compiler will not find the class.

So... say you have this structure in your folders:

```
src
->my
  ->package
    ->name
      ->ClassName
```

The class would be set up as so:

```
package my.package.name { 
    public class ClassName {
        public function ClassName(){
            //construct
        }
    }
}
```

And you would import it using:

```
import my.package.name.ClassName;
```

or

```
import my.package.name.*; //only use the wildcard if every class in that package is being used, otherwise you will include code you may or may not need to in your project
```

Hopefully that helps explain packages and imports a bit.

I also noticed that you are using the functions in your `CustomFuncs` class as if they were static (as you would with `Math.cos()` or similar). Your class is not set up to work this way. To do that, you need to use this `static` access modifier.

```
package sthreets 
{
    public class CustomFuncs 
    {
        public static function TopDownMove(xy:String, rot:Number, offSet:Number):Number
        {
            if(xy=="x")
            {
                return cos(DegreesToRadions(rot)+offSet)
            }
            if(xy=="y")
            {
                return sin(DegreesToRadions(rot)+offSet)
            }
        }

        public static function DegreesToRadions(rot:Number):Number
        {
            return rot*Math.PI/180;
        }
    }
}
```

The static access modifier means that the object (in this case, the functions) only exist once in any instance of the app, whereas a standard access modifier (`public`, `private`, `protected`, `internal`, `mx_internal`, `final`) create one object for every single instance of the *class*. Using the `static` access modifier allows you to access objects through `ClassName.objectName` because the objects belong to the class, not to the parent object. To get to those objects, you never have to instantiate (you will notice in the above code that I removed your constructor because it is unnecessary in this case).

**Note:** The following isn't necessarily directed at you, but I am including it for any future readers who might visit this question

This [blog post](http://greenethumb.com/article/27/public-private-protected-internal-access-modifiers-in-as3/) gives a fairly good rundown of the standard access modifiers. The comparisons it makes in relation to beer are incredibly good and incredibly easy for someone with limited knowledge about the modifiers to understand.

I also suggest reading this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable) on "Static Variable" to help you understand what a static object is and where and how to use it.

AS3 strictly follows OOP (object oriented programming) and ECMAScript policies and its syntax is based heavily on Java. For these reasons, nearly every principle used by other OOP or ECMA languages applies to AS3 as well. This means that you can improve your AS3 skills by reading up on these principles, even if they are not specifically for AS3 (AS3 OOP tutorials are fairly limited in both quantity and quality so it can be difficult for someone who is learning AS3 as their first OOP language to learn these principles).

Comment: Thanks, but how do I set it up if my fla/as files are in a folder on the desktop, but my custom class is also in a folder on the desktop? Also the sin/cos stuff with Math I was planning on debugging later but I intended Math.sin and Math.cos.

Comment: If they are in your src folder (in this case, the folder on your desktop), the package is the same as your document class. So there is no need to import it and the class should be created as `package{ public class{` without any package name. (Not 100% sure, however, since I have never built a class-based project using Flash Pro, only Flash Builder and Flash Develop. But Pro is just a much more feature-filled IDE so it should work the same)

Comment: They are in different folders, but I can't figure out what all to do, I tried Users._sthreet.Desktop and all that, tried several things but I can't figure out what the file path would be.

Comment: What is the folder path? The full thing for both the FLA and the class.

Comment: C:\Users\_sthreet\Desktop\sthreets for my custom class, C:\Users\_sthreet\Desktop\Maurader for the project I'm working on.

Comment: If the files are not in your application directory, you must include the files manually. File>ActionScript Settings. Add your folder. Flash doesn't know what folders to include and not include, so it only works with subdirectories of the src directory. Package at this point might not matter, though you should use proper naming conventions (com.yourdomain.project.category.subcategory.Class)

Comment: Sweet, thats what I'm looking for. however can I have examples for com.yourdomain.project.category.subcategory.class? I have never heard of that before and google gave very few results (when searching for as3 as well) and didn't seem to be about what I searched.

Comment: That is the generally accepted convention for package naming. I work for a company named Vuria whose website is vuria.com. All of my packages are `com.vuria.projectname.category`. If I worked for Mozilla, it would be `org.mozilla.firefox`. If I worked for Overstock, I'd use `co.o.projectname`.

Comment: hmm... well the one i'm trying to import isn't really specific to any project but i guess i'll try several dots instead of one. EDIT: Its autocompleteing, but I still get a "1172: Definition fun.co.sthreets could not be found" error.